# adding a new line in the text box

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, streamwriter

In the text file it prints on a new line but when it is displayed in  the text box it is on the same line any ideas how to fix this?

```
   {    
      string[] justJeansArray = new string[10];

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


    string filepath = Server.MapPath("~") + "//app_data\\justJeansBlog.txt";
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filepath);
    string justJeansstring = sr.ReadToEnd();
    string[] justJeansArray = justJeansstring.Split('\n');

     for (int i = justJeansArray.Length - 1; i > justJeansArray.Length - 6; i--)
    {
        blogTB.Text += justJeansArray[i] + "\n\n";
    }

    sr.Close();
}
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(Server.MapPath("~") +    "//app_data\\justJeansBlog.txt", true);
    sw.WriteLine(messageTB.Text);
    sw.Close();


    Response.Redirect("justJeans.aspx");
}
```

}

Comment: Make sure your Textbox's [TextMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.textmode(v=vs.110).aspx) is set to multiline

Answer (score 1):

Enable the [TextMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.textmode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property of your textbox to MultiLine to allow this:

```
blogTB.TextMode = TextBoxMode.MultiLine;
blogTB.Rows = 10;
```

Comment: That would be correct for winforms, he is asking about ASP.net though.